# Info about Auth in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, firebase-authentication

Info about Auth in Firebase Real-time Database

Hello everyone, in these days I made my first app in flutter that reads from a real-time Firebase database a list of data (cars info, because it’s a car catalog read from the main website).
In this moment database is in test mode, so read and write are set to true. 
I want that who downloaded app can read all cars list without sign in, so in this case I have to leave the read property with true value and the write one with false value ?
Or there is another better way to authorise people to read list without sign in, maybe with a key or other I don’t know.
Thank you very much who read all the message ☺️

Comment: The quesiton is a bit broad as apps usually have a multitude of nodes that contain different types of info. You may want to include an example of your structure so we can understand what data you want available. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebase console find `rules` tab for your database and set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

In this case anyone can read, but only authorized user can write

This tab:

[image]

Comment: @hobbit This is a great answer but that will allow all users to read *all* data within Firebase. For example they could read the car cost, or who the original owner was or the VIN number - things you may not just want available to anyone. It may be better to to 'lock down' just the /car_list node instead of all nodes, depending on your use case.

Comment: @Jay first of all thanks for the answers and advices.
There is no problem that users can read all the database's fields because there isn't nothing secret, I loaded inside DB only the fields that i needed, so i think that the configuration that Andrey gave me is enough.